# Can we mount file system as primary and secondary

Tags: linux

I need to mount file system as primary and secondary, if incase primary file system is down then it should store the files in secondary file system. Is that possible? if possible what are the options I should do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use disk mirroring ([RAID level 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_1)), many disk-controllers support this.

I believe Linux may support this in the OS using [MDADM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mdadm) (I have never used it).

Comment: Note that RAID1 would use separate disks, not just separate filesystems

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex question which (although not obviously) is difficult to answer as is. Here is the landscape.

RAID - RAID provides protection against hardware failure, and is a very good solution to the simple case. It does not actually meet your criteria, as its not writing to a second place if the first dies - but if this is loose wording of the question and RAID meets your needs - its the option to go for. Even if it doesn't meet your needs, its a good base to build on - as the solutions below will work with RAID.

If the primary filesystem is down, and you want to (and can) write to an alternative filesystem on the same box, you should look to a "union" filesystem.  These virtual filesystem's let you combine disks and merge different layers. They are how many "live USB disks" work. They layer multiple filesystem's in a given order with different ways ofcombining reads and writes.  Thee are a number of such systems like aufs, unionfs and overlayfs.  The challenge with these is managing how they manage the underlying filesystem becoming unavailable - you may need to periodically check and kill the unavailable layer and tweek the unionfs - which may defeat the purpose.

Another couple of options which are very overlooked ate drbd and MARS (which is technically superior, virtually unknown and not as well integrated). These solve a different problem by replicating the disk between multiple systems (think network raid).   If your plans call for robustness against PC failure these are worth looking at. You would presumably want to export the block device and use that.

Probably the best answer is to look at a filesystem like cluster (or moosefs or similar). There are built out of distributed blocks, with redundancy, and abstract it all away so your reads and writes can survive disk or hardware failure. I don't think these work well at a block level though.